# I need to add a variable to the url

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem in Laravel
I want to query the url by the date of sale and the branch number in the branch number is not executed

```
 $response = $client->request('GET', 'orders?filters[branch_hid]='.$Brn'&filters[business_date]='.$date,[
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please give us more information. Is this code in a controller?

Comment: I want to replace the fixed value _2791g6a7 with a variable named Branch

 $response = $client->request('GET', 'orders?filters[branch_hid]=_2791g6a7&filters[business_date]='.$date

Comment: can you post your full code ? also there's a syntax error in your code `ch_hid]='.$Brn'&filters` use this: `ch_hid]='.$Brn.'&filters`